# Will DDR4 2400Mhz RAM run on the MSI H170 GAMING M3 motherboard?

Tags: memory, performance, motherboard

first question to this forum and i would be happy if someone could help me.

I am building a PC and i have bought some components.
I already bought the motherboard MSI H170 GAMING M3 with these specs:

-Supports 6th Gen Intel® Core™ / Pentium® / Celeron® processors for LGA 1151 socket

-Supports DDR4-2133 Memory. Supports ECC, un-buffered memory

-DDR4 Boost: Give your DDR4 memory a performance boost

So i tend to buy a kingston RAM 8GB at 2400mHZ

My questions are:

1)The motherboard specs mention that it supports DDR4 2133MHZ, will this ram run smoothly on this motherboard? Can it run at full 2400Mhz?

2) In the near future i plan to buy one more RAM of the same type. Will it run on dual channel?

Thanks in advance

Comment: i do not tend to buy more RAM, the question here is for the first RAM that i will put on my System. I cannot run the programms that give the solution to the post you posted without any RAM to my PC...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use RAM that has a higher clock speed than the motherboard supports, the RAM will be clocked down to the maximum speed supported.

In your case the RAM wil work just fine, but will run at a maximum of 2133 MHz (if the CPU also supports this). This isn't really a problem, because RAM speed certainly on this speeds makes almost no different.

For your second question, on the motherboard specs page the following is said "Dual channel memory architecture". So it has support for dual channel memory.

If you use a single 8 GB stick it will of course not run in dual channel mode, but if you buy another stick later on and use the correct RAM slots it will run in dual channel mode.